# JQuery Animation Slowing Down on KeyPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm using JQuery to animate a div using the arrow keys.

For some reason when I repeat the arrow key press for the current direction, the animation slows dratically each time.

I thought `$player.stop()` and `$player.clearQueue()` would fix this, but apparently not. Any suggestions pleae?

There is a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qb484yp2/

My JS code is below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $player = $('#player'),
    $enemy1 = $('#enemy1'),
    $bg = $('#container'),
    playerW = $player.outerWidth(),
    playerH = $player.outerHeight(),
    bgW = $bg.width(),
    bgH = $bg.height(),
    playerX,
    playerY,
    enemySpeed = 1000,
    playerSpeed = 1000,
    direction,
    down = false;

    var targetSound1 = $('#targetSound1')[0];
    targetSound1.loop = true;

    function keypress(e) {

        $player.clearQueue();
        $player.stop()
        if (down) {
            return;
        }
        down = true;

        var playerLeft = $player.css('left');
        var playerTop = $player.css('top');
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if ([38, 40, 37, 39].includes(key)) {
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent defualts (scrolling)!
        }

        if (key == "37") {
            direction = 'left';
            playerLeft = 0;
        } else if (key == "38") {
            direction = 'up';
            playerTop = 0;
        } else if (key == "39") {
            direction = 'right';
            playerLeft = bgW - playerW;
        } else if (key == "40") {
            direction = 'down';
            playerTop = bgH - playerH;
        }

        $player.animate({
            left: playerLeft,
            top: playerTop
        },
            playerSpeed, 'linear');

    }

    function makeNewPosition($container) {

        // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
        $container = ($container || $(window))
        var h = $container.height() - 50;
        var w = $container.width() - 50;
        var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
        var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

        return [nh, nw];
    }

    function animateDiv() {

        var $target = $($enemy1);
        var newq = makeNewPosition($target.parent());
        var oldq = $target.offset();
        var speed = enemySpeed;

        $($enemy1).animate({
            top: newq[0],
            left: newq[1]
        }, speed, 'linear', function () {
            animateDiv();
        });
    };

    $(document).on('keydown', keypress);
    $(document).on('keyup', function () {
        down = false
    });

    animateDiv();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i checked out your fiddle. I played around with it a bit and i got a solution. heres the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/qb484yp2/3/

solution : so my logic was if the key that is triggering an event was the key that triggered the previous event, we shouldnt be animating the #player div any longer. Only if the key changes we should animate it. This will stop unneccesary animations from piling up and slowing down the animation. So i thought we could probably keep track of the last animation and only if the key pressed has changed we would allow the animation to occur. Result : Smooth animation :)

this is the code that did the trick! check out the fiddle for the entire code

```
if(key==lastKey)
{
return;
}
else
lastKey=key;
```

Also you'd have to remove this line from the code as it stops the animation of the player div.

```
$player.stop()
```

Comment: Nice! Simple and effective. Thanks.